# Isomorphism between l1 (of sequences) and Banach Space with unconditional basis

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, schauder-basis

Hi Guys I am terribly stuck on this question.

$u_n$ are an unconditional but not shrinking, norm 1 basis of a banach space $Y$, which is the closure of the span of $u_n$.

$l_1$ is the sapce of sequences with the sum of their absolute values of all elements being finite.

$T$ is defined to be $T\left(c\right)=\sum_{n \in N} c_nu_n$ where $c=$$\left(c_n\right)_{n \in N}$ is a sequence in $l_1$.

How do I show that T is an isomorphism between $l_1$ and $Y$?

I argued that as Y is the closure of span, every linear combination of $u_n$ is in Y, and as $u_n$ is a basis the mapping is injective from $l_1$ to $Y$. (I am not sure if that is right though). But I have no idea how to show surjectivity and that the mapping is bounded.

Can anyone please provide some hint?

Comment: Under your hypothesis the series defining $T$ may not converge. You have to assume that $\|u_n\|$ is bounded.

Comment: Thanks. I just updated the question. But do you have any idea about showing surjectivity?

Comment: $T$ need not be an isomorphism; taking $Y=\ell_2$ and $(u_n)$ to be its standard basis gives a counterexample.